# equivalent definitions of these ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove this question:

[image]

The notation:

[image]

I'm doing the first part.

I've already proved that the second $C_R$ above is contained in the first one (let's call it as $C_R'$). That's my reasoning:

$I\in C_R\implies I=J^c\implies Ker f\subset f^{-1}(J)$, which is obvious because $0\in J$, because $J$ is an ideal, then $I\in C_R'$.

I need help with the converse, I've already proved that because this function is surjective then Im$f$ is an ideal of $S$, my guess is to show that $J=f(I)$, but $f^{-1}(J)=f^{-1}(f(I))\neq I$

I really need help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant you had proved so far is that $C_R \subseteq C_R'$.

Proof of the converse; $C_R' \subseteq C_R$:

Let $I \in C_R'$, that is, let $I$ be an ideal in $R$ with $I \supseteq Ker f$. Then we **do have that** $f^{-1}(f(I)) = I$.

First, $I$ is obviously in  $f^{-1}(f(I))$.

Second, let $r \in  f^{-1}(f(I))$. Then $f(r) = f(r')$ for some $r'$ in $I$, and consequently, $f(r) - f(r') = f(r - r') = 0$, implying that $r - r' \in Ker f$. But, $Ker f \subseteq I$, and therefore $r - r' \in I$, and $r - r' = r''$ for some $r''$ in $I$, and $r = r' + r''$, where both $r', r''$ are in $I$, giving us $r$ also being in $I$.

To summarize, $r$ being in $f^{-1}(f(I))$ implies that $r$ is in $I$. Thus, $f^{-1}(f(I))$ $\subseteq I$. In conclusion, $f^{-1}(f(I))$ $= I$.